# Why isn't ffmpeg slicing my .mp4 video as it should?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xcf5480] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (avc3 / 0x33637661), none, 704x396, 1541 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
/home/elias/testing_vid.mp4: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/user/testing_vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso6
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6dash
  Duration: 00:00:59.76, start: 0.020000, bitrate: 1544 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: none (avc3 / 0x33637661), none, 704x396, 1541 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : USP Video Handler
      encoder         : Elemental H.264
No decoder for stream #0:0, filtering impossible
Error opening filters!
```

This is the error message i got, my ubuntu and ffmpeg versions are :

ffmpeg amd64 7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Can you please edit your question to include: what you were trying to achieve and what command have you tried running?

Comment: I tried a simpler example ffmpeg -i /home/user/testing_vid.mp4   -vf fps=1 /home/user/onepersec/out%d.png to get one image every second same error but then i tested another .flv vid and it works, why?!

Comment: TRied increasing the values of the parameters ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i /home/user/testing_vid.mp4 didn't work either same error.

Comment: I'm not fluent in `ffmpeg` and I won't answer your question unfortunately. I'm just suggesting that you include, in a clear way, **1. your goal**, **2. what you have tried** (including the command line options) into your questions, not in the comments.

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg. `avc3` indicates a video stream with changing parameter sets. That's not typical.

Answer (score 0):

*ffmpeg-2.8.15* in Ubuntu doesn't support that video codec *(avc3 / 0x33637661)*. Try to use an additional repository with the newer *ffmpeg-3.4.4*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```